# Insert or delete a step in scikit-learn Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

Is it possible to delete or insert a step in a `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` object?

I am trying to do a grid search with or without one step in the Pipeline object. And wondering whether I can insert or delete a step in the pipeline. I saw in the `Pipeline` source code, there is a `self.steps` object holding all the steps. We can get the steps by `named_steps()`.  Before modifying it, I want to make sure, I do not cause unexpected effects.

Here is a example code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
estimators = [('reduce_dim', PCA()), ('svm', SVC())]
clf = Pipeline(estimators)
clf
```

Is it possible that we do something like `steps = clf.named_steps()`, then insert or delete in this list? Does this cause undesired effect on the clf object?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I see that everyone mentioned only the delete step. In case you want to also insert a step in the pipeline:

```
pipe.steps.append(['step name',transformer()])
```

`pipe.steps` works in the same way as lists do, so you can also insert an item into a specific location:

```
pipe.steps.insert(1,['estimator',transformer()]) #insert as second step
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! I think the `append` or `insert` should be done with a `tuple` instead of a ` list` because each step in a pipeline is a `tuple`. As in: 
`pipe.steps.append(('step name',transformer()))` and `pipe.steps.insert(1,('estimator',transformer()))`

Answer (score 21):

Based on rudimentary testing you can safely remove a step from a scikit-learn pipeline just like you would any list item, with a simple

```
clf_pipeline.steps.pop(n)
```

where n is the position of the individual estimator you are trying to remove.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please expand on "based on rudimentary testing"?

Comment: I have about 500 pre-trained pipelines with identical vectorization steps. I transformed the incoming data using the vectorization step of one of these pipelines, then removed this step from all pipelines before running each pipeline's predict_proba method on the pre-vectorized data. The resultant scores were the same as if I had run each unmodified pipeline on the raw data without pre-vectorizing, and the overall runtime was improved since I wasn't doing the identical vectorization step over and over. Note that this only works with stateless transformers like the hashing vectorizer.

Comment: Perhaps you could have used caching instead by setting the `memory` param of the pipeline?

Answer (score 8):

Just chiming in because I feel like the other answers answered the question of adding steps to a pipeline really well, **but didn't really cover how to delete a step from a pipeline.**

Watch out with my approach though. Slicing lists in this instance is a bit weird.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

estimators = [('reduce_dim', PCA()), ('poly', PolynomialFeatures()), ('svm', SVC())]
clf = Pipeline(estimators)
```

If you want to create a pipeline with just steps PCA/Polynomial you can just slice the list step by indexes and pass it to Pipeline

```
clf1 = Pipeline(clf.steps[0:2])
```

Want to just use steps 2/3?
Watch out these slices don't always make the most amount of sense

```
clf2 = Pipeline(clf.steps[1:3])
```

Want to just use steps 1/3? 
I can't seem to do using this approach

```
clf3 = Pipeline(clf.steps[0] + clf.steps[2]) # errors
```

Comment: `clf3 = Pipeline([clf.steps[0], clf.steps[2]])`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible, but you must fulfill same requirements which Pipeline requires at initialization, i.e. you cannot insert predictor in any step except last, you should call `fit` after you update Pipeline.steps, because after such update all steps (maybe they were learned in previous `fit` calls) will be invalidated, also last step of Pipeline should always implement `fit` method, all previous steps should implement `fit_transform`.

So yes, it will work in current codebase, but i think it's not a good solution for your task, it makes your code more dependent on current implementation of Pipeline, i think it's more convenient to create new Pipeline with modified steps, because Pipeline will at least validate all your steps in initialization, also creating new Pipeline will not significantly differ in terms of speed from modifying steps of existing pipeline, but as i've just said - creation of new Pipeline after each modification of steps is safer in case when someone will significantly change implementation of Pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The concern on modifying steps directly also is my concern, that's why I asked whether there is a safe way to do this. Oh, about why I want to modify pipelines instead of creating new pipelines. The reason is because that I want to do a bunch of experiments with different pipeline. So modifying them in code is a preferred way. I agree that create new Pipeline is also a good way to go. I probably reconsider this. Thanks. (Still hoping some one have a way of modifying the steps safely :)

Comment: @IbraimGaniev, you said "you should call fit after you update Pipeline.", one can fit the pipeline, but for an empty pipeline, if one inserts a fitted transformer like `pipe.steps.insert(0,['estimator', fitted_transformer_instance])`, the pipe needn't be fit. Also, `sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted(pipe)` will not fail. all of this was tested with `scikit-learn==1.4.1`.