# Is there a way for sklearn pipeline to train with and without a step during a grid search? I can remove steps but how do i pass this to GridSearchCV?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search, hyperparameters

This got closed the first time I asked it because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34324192/10311199) asks something similar. However despite the answers showing how to add/remove from a step from the pipeline, none of them show how this works with `GridSearchCV` and I'm left wondering what to do with the pipeline that I've removed the step from.

I'd like to train a model using a grid search and test the performance both when PCA is performed first and when PCA is omitted.  Is there a way to do this? I'm looking for more than simply setting `n_components` to the number of input variables.

Currently I define my pipeline like this:

```py
pca = PCA()
gbc = GradientBoostingClassifier()
steps = [('pca', pca), ('gbc', gbc)]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)

param_grid = {
    'pca__n_components': [3, 5, 7],
    'gbc__n_estimators': [50, 100]
    }

search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, you can have a look at the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#nested-parameters) where it says under the paragraph for nested parameters:

> Individual steps may also be replaced as parameters, and non-final steps may be ignored by setting them to `'passthrough'`

In your case, I would define a grid with a list of two dictionaries, one in case the whole pipeline is used, and one where the `PCA` is omitted:

```py
param_grid = [
    {
        'pca__n_components': [3, 5, 7],
        'gbc__n_estimators': [50, 100]
    },
    {
        'pca': ['passthrough'], # skip the PCA
        'gbc__n_estimators': [50, 100]
    }
]
```

`GridSearchCV` will now span the grids according to each dictionary in the list and try combinations with and without `PCA`.

Comment: I haven't seen anyone use this before, much simpler answer than I was expecting